# what is the best way to implement paypal credit

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have an opencart store and I would like to integrate paypal credit in my store.There is no option with current extensions provided by opencart. What is the best way to integrate paypal credit in open cart. Basically I want to give paypal credit as another payment method. So my cart will have two payment methods.
1) Paypal express checkout
2) Paypal credit

Appreciate any help on this.

Best Regards,
Abhilash

Comment: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=paypal%20credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencart comes with Paypal standard extension. So if we enable paypal standard customer will be redirected to paypal site and there they will have the option for paypal credit.

Customer need to apply for paypla credit to avail this facility. This is available in sandbox mode as well. After customer make payment using paypla credit system will work same as user make paymant via his/her paypal account or credit card.